# Risk in density estimation: grasping the definition

Tags: nonparametric, expected-value, density-function, estimators, definition

When generalizing estimators to an entire function what is the space in which we perform the integral to obtain the expected value (with respect to this function)?

For example, when estimating parameters, the risk definition is

[image]

What happens with it when there are no parameters, but an entire function? What exactly would be an infinite-dimensional integral?